# More efficient assignment of numpy array elements based on category

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a single-dimension array with values grouped according to a natural break algorithm (Jenks, for the interested). I would like to make another array with elements based on the groups of the initial array. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1, 42, 1, 1, 2, 43, 2, 3, 44, 41, 42])
bins = np.array([1.0, 3.0, 44.0])
rank = 1 * (arr == bins[0])
# Next two lines to be optimized
for i in xrange(len(bins) - 1):
    rank[(arr > bins[i]) & (arr <= bins[i+1])] = bins[i+1]
print rank
# [ 1 44  1  1  3 44  3  3 44 44 44]
```

Explained, this goes through intervals *(a, b]* in `bins` and assigns to `rank` the value of *b* for all elements of `arr` in the interval. This code snippet produces the output I want, but the loop can take a long time when `bins` is large. Is there a more efficient way to do this, possibly using some numpy tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `numpy.searchsorted` function.  I think it will be faster than nearly any loop you write yourself.

```
arr = np.array([1, 42, 1, 1, 2, 43, 2, 3, 44, 41, 42])
bins = np.array([1.0, 3.0, 44.0])
rank = bins[np.searchsorted(bins, arr)]
print rank
[  1.  44.   1.   1.   3.  44.   3.   3.  44.  44.  44.]
```

There is also `numpy.histogram` which you might want to look at too.  It's easier to understand, but internally it also uses `searchsorted`.

***Update:*** I compared timing on your example arrays with `timeit`.

```
%timeit rank = bins[np.searchsorted(bins, arr)]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.51 µs per loop
```

This compares well to your original loop:

```
%timeit for i in xrange(len(bins) - 1): rank[(arr > bins[i]) & (arr <= bins[i+1])] = bins[i+1]
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.78 µs per loop
```

Comment: Much more efficient! And the speed gains are huge with larger arrays. Just with size 200 for `arr` and `bin`, this method is over 88x faster than the original loop. For size 2000 on both, I'm clocking a 294x speed gain!

Answer (score 1):

The loop could be simplified, if not sped up, with:

```
In [132]: rank1=np.ones(arr.shape,dtype=bins.dtype)

In [133]: for i in range(len(bins)-1):
    rank1[arr>bins[i]]=bins[i+1]
   .....:     

In [134]: rank1
Out[134]: array([  1.,  44.,   1.,   1.,   3.,  44.,   3.,   3.,  44.,  44.,  44.])
```

But here's a way of generating the same thing using array operations.

```
In [135]: rank2=bins[np.sum(arr[None,:]>bins[:,None],axis=0)]

In [136]: rank2
Out[136]: array([  1.,  44.,   1.,   1.,   3.,  44.,   3.,   3.,  44.,  44.,  44.])
```

Is it better?  It might be more obscure.  In time tests on your small example, these 2 versions take the same time, and are about 2x the speed of your version.

Comment: That's great! The second method is substantially quicker with a large number of bins. Changing `bin` length to 200, I get about 15.5x speedup. This goes down with size of `arr`, although if I set the length of `arr` at 200 as well, I still get almost 3x speedup. Makes sense. Method 1 expends time on looping over bins, method 2 on array operation. Which one is quicker therefore depends on the relative size of `arr` and `bins`.